# spark sql - alias column can not be resolved

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm migrating a script to spark-sql, it assembles some cases and reuses the result of these cases for other operations, but I can't use the reference column in my script.

example:

```
SELECT order, 
       case when total > 70 
            then 1 
            end order_total,
       coalesce(order_total,total) as total    
FROM SALES
```

When running the script I get the message:

cannot resolve '`order_total`' given input columns: ...

the query above is just an example, my script has several similar operations, I know that using cte's or subquerys works, but I wanted to know if it is possible to use the above form in spark.

the query above is just an example, my script has several similar operations, I know that using cte's or subquerys works, but I wanted to know if it is possible to use the above form in spark.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use aliases in a select, at the same time, when you want it in one go you need to repeat it

```
SELECT 
   order
   , case when total > 70 then 1 end order_total
   , coalesce(case when total > 70 then 1 end,total) as total
FROM SALES
```

Comment: Using subquery or cte I know it's possible, the problem is that my script I do this type several times, it's a script migrated from redshift.

Comment: you can use a cte for that or replace all alias values that you want touse, that is life in sql, so my answer stays as one option, the other with a cte is the other